# listing a listview is taking too much time and memory in android

Tags: android

i 3 classes, one which contains the list view and is the acitivity. second class is a adapter that i have built to populate the listview. third class which interacts with the database and gives info to the second class.

the functioning of all the three classes when i do the following:

`listview.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter())`

it is taking a whole of time because there are many records to display. 
i want to use multithreading over here.
how do i go about it?
i know of `AsyncTask`. would it work if i kept the above mentioned statement in the `doInBackground()` method, but how will i know when the list is populated?

SOLUTION:

Got a solution. i am passing the progressdialog object from the mainactivity class into the custom adapter. over there in the `getView` method i am checking whether the int arg0 (the variable giving the position in the dataset) has reached the end. upon this i dismiss the progressdialog that i have passed.

Comment: Can you please help me out. I am facing the same problem but I don't got your solution. Please provide sample code for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just show a certain amount of items, and add more items when the user scrolls to the bottom.

Here is a nice example on how to do this;

http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-dynamicaly-load-more-items-to-the-listview-never-ending-list/

Comment: how do i do this? i mean all the vies are made when i call the adapter. how do i control how many views are made?

Comment: Can you show some more code on how you are loading the ListView right now? Then I can hook into that and show you an example

Comment: as explained in the question. i have three classes. all the three are involved in the loading, which class code do you want to see?

Answer (score 0):

The AsyncaTask class contains methods like onProgressUpdate and publishProgress. So whenever you get some data you could call publishProgress to indicate that some data has been received.

Then in onProgressUpdate, you could show the data. Thus, the user does not have to see a Progress bar for too long and he can view the items as they appear.

Comment: i could do this if all the things are within one class. there are three separate classes over here. how do i do the above using separate classes?

Comment: Is your AsyncTask called in CustomAdapter or the Main Activity? I have a logic but I guess it will cause refreshing of the listView far too often. Have a counter say you want to display 10 items, retrieve them from the db by calling retrieval methods in doInBackground, then publishProgress and in onProgressUpdate call your setAdapter method

Comment: This has a flaw that it will keep on refreshing the listview a lot.

Comment: asynctask is in the main activity

Comment: @chaitanya Can you please provide me an example or sample of that.

Answer (score 0):

The list control is smart enough to create only needed number of views which is equal to the max number of visible view + 2 extra. When you scroll down it reuses the views. I guess that the time consuming operation is in creating a single view. Are you loading something from remote address ?

Comment: correct. it is taking a lot of time to make one view. this is because i have a lot of database operations going on to retrieve data to put in a single view.

Comment: My suggestion is to cache some how the results from the DB. You can retrieve all the needed data(the one which will be displayed) in an array object. The access to the array is much faster than the db.

Comment: the database is accessed only once. after this the result is being stored in an array. i want to show a progress dialog or something until this action is completed.

Comment: You can use asynctask as you mentioned before but I'm not sure how you can detect whether the list is populated or not. I will solve this like that: I'll display a loader in each item, and when the item is loaded I 'll switch to it's real content. In the code I will create stub views which will be swapped with a real ones when the loading is complete.