# Progress Bar during the loading of a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask

So, I want to display a spinning loading indicator while my ListView is being populated. I successfully have implemented the progress bar, BUT for some reason it disappears BEFORE all of the listings are displayed. What I want is the progressbar to be present during the TOTAL load time of the listings. Basically, what it seems like, each listing is being displayed one at a time, not all at once when they are all loaded.
What I'm doing is
  1. Creating a new custom adapter class
  2. Populating the ListView in an AsyncTask using this adapter class
  3. Setting the ListView to this adapter

This works properly, the progress bar just disappears before all of the listings are displayed. Does anyone have any ideas?

Activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ArrayList<Location> arrayOfLocations;
LocationAdapter adapter;
// public static Bitmap bitmap;
Button refresh;
ProgressBar progress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    progress=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar_loading);
    // Construct the data source
    arrayOfLocations = new ArrayList<Location>();

    // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
    adapter = new LocationAdapter(this, arrayOfLocations);

    FillLocations myFill = new FillLocations();
    myFill.execute();



    refresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.refresh);
    refresh.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
        }
    });

}


private class FillLocations extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, String> {
    String msg = "Done";

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        String result = "";
        InputStream isr = null;
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://afs.spotcontent.com/"); // YOUR
                                                                                // PHP
                                                                                // SCRIPT
                                                                                // ADDRESS
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            isr = entity.getContent();
            // resultView.setText("connected");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }
        // convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(isr, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            isr.close();

            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error  converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // parse json data
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                final JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                try {

                    BitmapWorkerTask myTask = new BitmapWorkerTask(
                            json.getInt("ID"), json);
                    myTask.execute();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data " + e.toString());
        }
        return msg;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
        // Attach the adapter to a ListView
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        // View header = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
        // R.layout.listview_header, null);
        // listView.addHeaderView(header);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
}
}
```

Adapter class:

```
public class LocationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Location> {
public LocationAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Location> locations) {
   super(context, R.layout.item_location, locations);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   // Get the data item for this position
   Location location = getItem(position);    
   // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
   if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_location, parent, false);
   }

   // Lookup view for data population
   TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
   TextView tvDetails = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDetails);
   TextView tvDistance = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDistance);
   TextView tvHours = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvHours);
   ImageView ivIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);

   // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
   tvName.setText(location.name);
   tvDetails.setText(location.details);
   tvDistance.setText(location.distance);
   tvHours.setText(location.hours);
   ivIcon.setImageBitmap(location.icon);
   // Return the completed view to render on screen
   return convertView;
}
}
```

Comment: How big is your ListView? If your data comes from local, maybe progress situation shown instantly and you can't see anything

Comment: They aren't coming from local, right now there is 60 items. But the indicator disappears after the first one is displayed. I want it so disappear only when ALL are displayed. I'm struggling to find out how to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for that behavior is that you are starting multiple threads.

```
FillLocations preExecute --> SHOW ProgressBar
BitmapWorkerTask_1 --> new thread
BitmapWorkerTask_2 --> new thread
...
BitmapWorkerTask_N --> new thread

FillLocations postExecute --> HIDE ProgressBar
BitmapWorkerTask_K --> continue execution
BitmapWorkerTask_K+1 --> continue execution
```

etc.

If you want the list to be displayed until it's all loaded, Simply make BitmapWorker's processing synchronous. If you still want to display the list right away but keep the spinner until it's all finished, then keep a counter in your activity and increase it in preexecute and decrease it in postExecute of BitmapWorker via a setter. Once the counter hits 0, remove hide the progressBar.

In activity:

```
private int asynchCounter = 0;
private void updateCounter(int delta){
    asynchCounter+=delta;
    if(asynchCounter<=0){
        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else{
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

And instead of BitmapWorkerTask use

```
class CountedBitmapWorkerTask extends BitmapWorkerTask {
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    updateCounter(1);
}
protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
        super.onPostExecute();
        updateCounter(-1);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm confused as to what the first bit of code is doing exactly.

Comment: It keeps track of the number of "active" or "running" CountedBitmapWorkerTasks. Then it displays the progress bar only when there are none running which means that all your images were downloaded

Comment: So for BitmapWorkerTask, the code you gave will be in ADDITION to what I have, correct?

Comment: You are correct, I updated the answer to call super.onPreExecute() and super.onPostExecute()

Comment: Hm, I have implemented this and my app freezes

Comment: Here is a fully working example I created: https://github.com/andresesfm/ProgressBarBackgroundImageLoading

Comment: I didn't use your solution BUT you really helped by making the problem clear: that I was starting a thread for each one. That helped me solve it. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I had this exact problem, to solve it I had to write `AsyncTask` complete listener. Which sends a notification to UI thread, that data was loaded and it has to change something, in this case hide the `ProgressBar`.

This is the basic example of how this should look like. I am not sure this will work for you after you copy it to your project, but complete listener is what you need, so after studying this case you should be able to find a solution.

**AsyncTaskCompleteListener.java** - listener interface.

```
public interface AsyncTaskCompleteListener {
       public void onTaskComplete();
}
```

**LoadDataTask.java**

```
class LoadDataTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> { 
    /* Your object types according to your task. */

    private AsyncTaskCompleteListener callback; // Callback field

    public LoadDataTask(AsyncTaskCompleteListener cb){
        this.callback = cb; 
    }

    @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(String... urls) {
        /* Your task here */
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
           callback.onTaskComplete(); // Set the Callback
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
   public class MainActivity implements AsyncTaskCompleteListener{
       /* ...Other methods and fields... */


       /* onTaskComplete method which fires after your data is loaded. */
       @Override
       public void onTaskComplete(){
           // Hide ProgressBar
       }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tony. I can't seem to get this working right, would you happen to have any links to where you got this information so I can read into it? Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry for not expanding. I got this from my own project but here's some details on similar case. http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/extracting-out-your-asynctasks-into-separate-classes-makes-your-code-cleaner/

Answer (score -1):

Self Plug: https://github.com/horvste/EasyWebPageDownloadForAndroid

This would separate the threading from the implementation and solve your problem. This is very similar to what Tony suggested except it's already implemented for you.

Github Readme:


Good for connecting to REST API's, HTML parsing, and many other uses. Using this library is meant to be easy:

1. Create a class which implements OnProgressUpdate

public class SampleClass implements OnProgressUpdate {

```
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Integer percentProgress) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateFailure() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(StringBuilder result) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure() {

    }
}
```

}
Instantiate DownloadWebPage object

```
DownloadWebPage webPage = new DownloadWebPage(new SampleClass(), myUrl);
```

Call .downloadHtml() from the DownloadWebPage

```
webPage.downloadHtml();
```

Also if the asynchtask is updating properly and the amount of items is to large look here:
[listing a listview is taking too much time and memory in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908493/listing-a-listview-is-taking-too-much-time-and-memory-in-android)

Another option would be to only list a certain amount of items then have a next page button or gesture to deal with the ListView loading too slow.